Getting research award and then ghosted?
I am being offered a research award at a university in a western europe country, and it's a quite known one as well in that country (well you can say in Europe as well). The research award is not from the university directly, it is from a research center within the university.
The award is a funding for a short research stay and I have accepted it. However, I have never heard back anything and my e-mails are not replied; it's been months since my acceptance email, and a month from my last e-mail (asking about the next step).
Is it possible that I am being ghosted? I don't mind if it's being cancelled (it's unpleasant, but what can I do, right?) at least there is a news.
Note: I don't know if I am ghosted. It is my question if it's possible that I am being ghosted? Because there is no response or news from the people that offered me this research award. Or is this a normal thing?

Hi. Welcome to Academia SE! I'm not sure what is your question exactly, could you please clarify a little?

My question is: is it possible to be ghosted after being awarded a research award?
I meant, is it normal not to get any news from them concerning the award? and no response to my emails like in months? I am not expecting a quick one day email response. Is this clearer now?

Bureaucracy in some EU countries (not all) can be quite slow and unresponsive.

You're being too passive. Call them today and get some kind of status update.

Indeed, sometime email gets blocked.  Phone, fax, send via an different email account on a different server.

You guys think so? because I dont wanna come across to be a nuisance.. I meant I know that people get lots of emails and my email can be buried among other emails. But, I did get reply before I accepted their offered.. It just frustrating that I get no news.. but, yes thanks, I will think about it.

@TerryLoring Fax ?!
